# How do I draw a symbol for vacuum diode in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

Can somebody help me to draw a symbol for a vacuum diode as is in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: You want to start adding vacuum tubes?  Anyway, a diode is a diode.

Comment: If I were going to add one vacuum tube, I'd like to do them all: http://www.rfcafe.com/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, vacuum tubes have been added to circuitikz.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[diodetube] {};
\draw (1.5,0) node[diodetube, xscale=-1] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image: two vacuum tubes]